# How to Enable GZIP compression on Play Framework 1 app on Heroku Cedar?

Tags: heroku, playframework, compression, gzip, cedar

I'd like to enable GZIP compression for public assets and HTTP responses for performance. My site has a lot of mobile access.

As far as I can tell, there is nothing built into Play Framework to support this, and Heroku doesn't seem to have a solution either.

What is the best way to start getting some compression on my app?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Check out: https://gist.github.com/1317626

Comment: Looks good. Any idea how to do it for static files in public directory - like HTML?

Comment: You'd need to wrap the Controller that serves static content.  I haven't look into how to do that.  Sorry.

Comment: Here's my attempt at minifying and gzipping static resources. Seems to work ok for me: https://gist.github.com/2882360

Answer (score 6):

Ok I've had a go at minifying and gzipping all STATIC resources - nobody seems to have attempted this yet.

Play provides a hook by means of a plugin, but it seems a little hacky as you have to set all the caching headers and stuff.

Seems to work so far though:

https://gist.github.com/2882360

Answer (score 5):

Check Minifymod module: 
http://www.playmodules.net/module/7