# JS compression - PageSpeed (Google Chrome report)

Tags: javascript, performance, compression

I'm running PageSpeed google chrome extension to check performance of my webpage. I believe I have got compressed JS file (See attached code) but report says It can be compressed again to get 59% reduction. Am I missing something here?

Update: We are using play framework. Can this be done using require.js optimizer?

[image]

```
/*
 RequireJS 2.0.4 Copyright (c) 2010-2012, The Dojo Foundation All Rights Reserved.
 Available via the MIT or new BSD license.
 see: http://github.com/jrburke/requirejs for details
*/
var requirejs,require,define;
(function(Y){function x(b){return J.call(b)==="[object Function]"}function G(b){return J.call(b)==="[object Array]"}function q(b,c){if(b){var e;for(e=0;e<b.length;e+=1)if(b[e]&&c(b[e],e,b))break}}function N(b,c){if(b){var e;for(e=b.length-1;e>-1;e-=1)if(b[e]&&c(b[e],e,b))break}}function y(b,c){for(var e in b)if(b.hasOwnProperty(e)&&c(b[e],e))break}function K(b,c,e,i){c&&y(c,function(c,j){if(e||!b.hasOwnProperty(j))i&&typeof c!=="string"?(b[j]||(b[j]={}),K(b[j],c,e,i)):b[j]=c});return b}function s(b,
c){return function(){return c.apply(b,arguments)}}function Z(b){if(!b)return b;var c=Y;q(b.split("."),function(b){c=c[b]});return c}function $(b,c,e){return function(){var i=fa.call(arguments,0),g;if(e&&x(g=i[i.length-1]))g.__requireJsBuild=!0;i.push(c);return b.apply(null,i)}}function aa(b,c,e){q([["toUrl"],["undef"],["defined","requireDefined"],["specified","requireSpecified"]],function(i){var g=i[1]||i[0];b[i[0]]=c?$(c[g],e):function(){var b=z[O];return b[g].apply(b,arguments)}})}function H(b,
c,e,i){c=Error(c+"\nhttp://requirejs.org/docs/errors.html#"+b);c.requireType=b;c.requireModules=i;if(e)c.originalError=e;return c}function ga(){if(I&&I.readyState==="interactive")return I;N(document.getElementsByTagName("script"),function(b){if(b.readyState==="interactive")return I=b});return I}var ha=/(\/\*([\s\S]*?)\*\/|([^:]|^)\/\/(.*)$)/mg,ia=/[^.]\s*require\s*\(\s*["']([^'"\s]+)["']\s*\)/g,ba=/\.js$/,ja=/^\.\//,J=Object.prototype.toString,A=Array.prototype,fa=A.slice,ka=A.splice,w=!!(typeof window!==
"undefined"&&navigator&&document),ca=!w&&typeof importScripts!=="undefined",la=w&&navigator.platform==="PLAYSTATION 3"?/^complete$/:/^(complete|loaded)$/,O="_",S=typeof opera!=="undefined"&&opera.toString()==="[object Opera]",z={},p={},P=[],L=!1,j,t,C,u,D,I,E,da,ea;if(typeof define==="undefined"){if(typeof requirejs!=="undefined"){if(x(requirejs))return;p=requirejs;requirejs=void 0}typeof require!=="undefined"&&!x(require)&&(p=require,require=void 0);j=requirejs=function(b,c,e,i){var g=O,r;!G(b)&&
typeof b!=="string"&&(r=b,G(c)?(b=c,c=e,e=i):b=[]);if(r&&r.context)g=r.context;(i=z[g])||(i=z[g]=j.s.newContext(g));r&&i.configure(r);return i.require(b,c,e)};j.config=function(b){return j(b)};require||(require=j);j.version="2.0.4";j.jsExtRegExp=/^\/|:|\?|\.js$/;j.isBrowser=w;A=j.s={contexts:z,newContext:function(b){function c(a,d,o){var l=d&&d.split("/"),f=l,b=k.map,c=b&&b["*"],e,g,h;if(a&&a.charAt(0)===".")if(d){f=k.pkgs[d]?l=[d]:l.slice(0,l.length-1);d=a=f.concat(a.split("/"));for(f=0;d[f];f+=
1)if(e=d[f],e===".")d.splice(f,1),f-=1;else if(e==="..")if(f===1&&(d[2]===".."||d[0]===".."))break;else f>0&&(d.splice(f-1,2),f-=2);f=k.pkgs[d=a[0]];a=a.join("/");f&&a===d+"/"+f.main&&(a=d)}else a.indexOf("./")===0&&(a=a.substring(2));if(o&&(l||c)&&b){d=a.split("/");for(f=d.length;f>0;f-=1){g=d.slice(0,f).join("/");if(l)for(e=l.length;e>0;e-=1)if(o=b[l.slice(0,e).join("/")])if(o=o[g]){h=o;break}!h&&c&&c[g]&&(h=c[g]);if(h){d.splice(0,f,h);a=d.join("/");break}}}return a}function e(a){w&&q(document.getElementsByTagName("script"),
function(d){if(d.getAttribute("data-requiremodule")===a&&d.getAttribute("data-requirecontext")===h.contextName)return d.parentNode.removeChild(d),!0})}function i(a){var d=k.paths[a];if(d&&G(d)&&d.length>1)return e(a),d.shift(),h.undef(a),h.require([a]),!0}function g(a,d,o,b){var f=a?a.indexOf("!"):-1,v=null,e=d?d.name:null,g=a,i=!0,j="",k,m;a||(i=!1,a="_@r"+(N+=1));f!==-1&&(v=a.substring(0,f),a=a.substring(f+1,a.length));v&&(v=c(v,e,b),m=n[v]);a&&(v?j=m&&m.normalize?m.normalize(a,function(a){return c(a,
e,b)}):c(a,e,b):(j=c(a,e,b),k=h.nameToUrl(j)));a=v&&!m&&!o?"_unnormalized"+(O+=1):"";return{prefix:v,name:j,parentMap:d,unnormalized:!!a,url:k,originalName:g,isDefine:i,id:(v?v+"!"+j:j)+a}}function r(a){var d=a.id,o=m[d];o||(o=m[d]=new h.Module(a));return o}function p(a,d,o){var b=a.id,f=m[b];if(n.hasOwnProperty(b)&&(!f||f.defineEmitComplete))d==="defined"&&o(n[b]);else r(a).on(d,o)}function B(a,d){var b=a.requireModules,l=!1;if(d)d(a);else if(q(b,function(d){if(d=m[d])d.error=a,d.events.error&&(l=
!0,d.emit("error",a))}),!l)j.onError(a)}function u(){P.length&&(ka.apply(F,[F.length-1,0].concat(P)),P=[])}function t(a,d,b){a=a&&a.map;d=$(b||h.require,a,d);aa(d,h,a);d.isBrowser=w;return d}function z(a){delete m[a];q(M,function(d,b){if(d.map.id===a)return M.splice(b,1),d.defined||(h.waitCount-=1),!0})}function A(a,d){var b=a.map.id,l=a.depMaps,f;if(a.inited){if(d[b])return a;d[b]=!0;q(l,function(a){if(a=m[a.id])return!a.inited||!a.enabled?(f=null,delete d[b],!0):f=A(a,K({},d))});return f}}function C(a,
d,b){var l=a.map.id,f=a.depMaps;if(a.inited&&a.map.isDefine){if(d[l])return n[l];d[l]=a;q(f,function(f){var f=f.id,c=m[f];!Q[f]&&c&&(!c.inited||!c.enabled?b[l]=!0:(c=C(c,d,b),b[f]||a.defineDepById(f,c)))});a.check(!0);return n[l]}}function D(a){a.check()}function E(){var a=k.waitSeconds*1E3,d=a&&h.startTime+a<(new Date).getTime(),b=[],l=!1,f=!0,c,g,j;if(!T){T=!0;y(m,function(a){c=a.map;g=c.id;if(a.enabled&&!a.error)if(!a.inited&&d)i(g)?l=j=!0:(b.push(g),e(g));else if(!a.inited&&a.fetched&&c.isDefine&&
(l=!0,!c.prefix))return f=!1});if(d&&b.length)return a=H("timeout","Load timeout for modules: "+b,null,b),a.contextName=h.contextName,B(a);f&&(q(M,function(a){if(!a.defined){var a=A(a,{}),d={};a&&(C(a,d,{}),y(d,D))}}),y(m,D));if((!d||j)&&l)if((w||ca)&&!U)U=setTimeout(function(){U=0;E()},50);T=!1}}function V(a){r(g(a[0],null,!0)).init(a[1],a[2])}function J(a){var a=a.currentTarget||a.srcElement,d=h.onScriptLoad;a.detachEvent&&!S?a.detachEvent("onreadystatechange",d):a.removeEventListener("load",d,
!1);d=h.onScriptError;a.detachEvent&&!S||a.removeEventListener("error",d,!1);return{node:a,id:a&&a.getAttribute("data-requiremodule")}}var k={waitSeconds:7,baseUrl:"./",paths:{},pkgs:{},shim:{}},m={},W={},F=[],n={},R={},N=1,O=1,M=[],T,X,h,Q,U;Q={require:function(a){return t(a)},exports:function(a){a.usingExports=!0;if(a.map.isDefine)return a.exports=n[a.map.id]={}},module:function(a){return a.module={id:a.map.id,uri:a.map.url,config:function(){return k.config&&k.config[a.map.id]||{}},exports:n[a.map.id]}}};
X=function(a){this.events=W[a.id]||{};this.map=a;this.shim=k.shim[a.id];this.depExports=[];this.depMaps=[];this.depMatched=[];this.pluginMaps={};this.depCount=0};X.prototype={init:function(a,d,b,l){l=l||{};if(!this.inited){this.factory=d;if(b)this.on("error",b);else this.events.error&&(b=s(this,function(a){this.emit("error",a)}));this.depMaps=a&&a.slice(0);this.depMaps.rjsSkipMap=a.rjsSkipMap;this.errback=b;this.inited=!0;this.ignore=l.ignore;l.enabled||this.enabled?this.enable():this.check()}},defineDepById:function(a,
d){var b;q(this.depMaps,function(d,f){if(d.id===a)return b=f,!0});return this.defineDep(b,d)},defineDep:function(a,d){this.depMatched[a]||(this.depMatched[a]=!0,this.depCount-=1,this.depExports[a]=d)},fetch:function(){if(!this.fetched){this.fetched=!0;h.startTime=(new Date).getTime();var a=this.map;if(this.shim)t(this,!0)(this.shim.deps||[],s(this,function(){return a.prefix?this.callPlugin():this.load()}));else return a.prefix?this.callPlugin():this.load()}},load:function(){var a=this.map.url;R[a]||
(R[a]=!0,h.load(this.map.id,a))},check:function(a){if(this.enabled&&!this.enabling){var d=this.map.id,b=this.depExports,c=this.exports,f=this.factory,e;if(this.inited)if(this.error)this.emit("error",this.error);else{if(!this.defining){this.defining=!0;if(this.depCount<1&&!this.defined){if(x(f)){if(this.events.error)try{c=h.execCb(d,f,b,c)}catch(g){e=g}else c=h.execCb(d,f,b,c);if(this.map.isDefine)if((b=this.module)&&b.exports!==void 0&&b.exports!==this.exports)c=b.exports;else if(c===void 0&&this.usingExports)c=
this.exports;if(e)return e.requireMap=this.map,e.requireModules=[this.map.id],e.requireType="define",B(this.error=e)}else c=f;this.exports=c;if(this.map.isDefine&&!this.ignore&&(n[d]=c,j.onResourceLoad))j.onResourceLoad(h,this.map,this.depMaps);delete m[d];this.defined=!0;h.waitCount-=1;h.waitCount===0&&(M=[])}this.defining=!1;if(!a&&this.defined&&!this.defineEmitted)this.defineEmitted=!0,this.emit("defined",this.exports),this.defineEmitComplete=!0}}else this.fetch()}},callPlugin:function(){var a=
this.map,d=a.id,b=g(a.prefix,null,!1,!0);p(b,"defined",s(this,function(b){var f=this.map.name,e=this.map.parentMap?this.map.parentMap.name:null;if(this.map.unnormalized){if(b.normalize&&(f=b.normalize(f,function(a){return c(a,e,!0)})||""),b=g(a.prefix+"!"+f,this.map.parentMap,!1,!0),p(b,"defined",s(this,function(a){this.init([],function(){return a},null,{enabled:!0,ignore:!0})})),b=m[b.id]){if(this.events.error)b.on("error",s(this,function(a){this.emit("error",a)}));b.enable()}}else f=s(this,function(a){this.init([],
function(){return a},null,{enabled:!0})}),f.error=s(this,function(a){this.inited=!0;this.error=a;a.requireModules=[d];y(m,function(a){a.map.id.indexOf(d+"_unnormalized")===0&&z(a.map.id)});B(a)}),f.fromText=function(a,d){var b=L;b&&(L=!1);r(g(a));j.exec(d);b&&(L=!0);h.completeLoad(a)},b.load(a.name,t(a.parentMap,!0,function(a,d){a.rjsSkipMap=!0;return h.require(a,d)}),f,k)}));h.enable(b,this);this.pluginMaps[b.id]=b},enable:function(){this.enabled=!0;if(!this.waitPushed)M.push(this),h.waitCount+=
1,this.waitPushed=!0;this.enabling=!0;q(this.depMaps,s(this,function(a,d){var b,c;if(typeof a==="string"){a=g(a,this.map.isDefine?this.map:this.map.parentMap,!1,!this.depMaps.rjsSkipMap);this.depMaps[d]=a;if(b=Q[a.id]){this.depExports[d]=b(this);return}this.depCount+=1;p(a,"defined",s(this,function(a){this.defineDep(d,a);this.check()}));this.errback&&p(a,"error",this.errback)}b=a.id;c=m[b];!Q[b]&&c&&!c.enabled&&h.enable(a,this)}));y(this.pluginMaps,s(this,function(a){var b=m[a.id];b&&!b.enabled&&
h.enable(a,this)}));this.enabling=!1;this.check()},on:function(a,b){var c=this.events[a];c||(c=this.events[a]=[]);c.push(b)},emit:function(a,b){q(this.events[a],function(a){a(b)});a==="error"&&delete this.events[a]}};return h={config:k,contextName:b,registry:m,defined:n,urlFetched:R,waitCount:0,defQueue:F,Module:X,makeModuleMap:g,configure:function(a){a.baseUrl&&a.baseUrl.charAt(a.baseUrl.length-1)!=="/"&&(a.baseUrl+="/");var b=k.pkgs,c=k.shim,e=k.paths,f=k.map;K(k,a,!0);k.paths=K(e,a.paths,!0);if(a.map)k.map=
K(f||{},a.map,!0,!0);if(a.shim)y(a.shim,function(a,b){G(a)&&(a={deps:a});if(a.exports&&!a.exports.__buildReady)a.exports=h.makeShimExports(a.exports);c[b]=a}),k.shim=c;if(a.packages)q(a.packages,function(a){a=typeof a==="string"?{name:a}:a;b[a.name]={name:a.name,location:a.location||a.name,main:(a.main||"main").replace(ja,"").replace(ba,"")}}),k.pkgs=b;y(m,function(a,b){a.map=g(b)});if(a.deps||a.callback)h.require(a.deps||[],a.callback)},makeShimExports:function(a){var b;return typeof a==="string"?
(b=function(){return Z(a)},b.exports=a,b):function(){return a.apply(Y,arguments)}},requireDefined:function(a,b){var c=g(a,b,!1,!0).id;return n.hasOwnProperty(c)},requireSpecified:function(a,b){a=g(a,b,!1,!0).id;return n.hasOwnProperty(a)||m.hasOwnProperty(a)},require:function(a,d,c,e){var f;if(typeof a==="string"){if(x(d))return B(H("requireargs","Invalid require call"),c);if(j.get)return j.get(h,a,d);a=g(a,d,!1,!0);a=a.id;return!n.hasOwnProperty(a)?B(H("notloaded",'Module name "'+a+'" has not been loaded yet for context: '+
b)):n[a]}c&&!x(c)&&(e=c,c=void 0);d&&!x(d)&&(e=d,d=void 0);for(u();F.length;)if(f=F.shift(),f[0]===null)return B(H("mismatch","Mismatched anonymous define() module: "+f[f.length-1]));else V(f);r(g(null,e)).init(a,d,c,{enabled:!0});E();return h.require},undef:function(a){var b=g(a,null,!0),c=m[a];delete n[a];delete R[b.url];delete W[a];if(c){if(c.events.defined)W[a]=c.events;z(a)}},enable:function(a){m[a.id]&&r(a).enable()},completeLoad:function(a){var b=k.shim[a]||{},c=b.exports&&b.exports.exports,
e,f;for(u();F.length;){f=F.shift();if(f[0]===null){f[0]=a;if(e)break;e=!0}else f[0]===a&&(e=!0);V(f)}f=m[a];if(!e&&!n[a]&&f&&!f.inited)if(k.enforceDefine&&(!c||!Z(c)))if(i(a))return;else return B(H("nodefine","No define call for "+a,null,[a]));else V([a,b.deps||[],b.exports]);E()},toUrl:function(a,b){var e=a.lastIndexOf("."),g=null;e!==-1&&(g=a.substring(e,a.length),a=a.substring(0,e));return h.nameToUrl(c(a,b&&b.id,!0),g)},nameToUrl:function(a,b){var c,e,f,g,h,i;if(j.jsExtRegExp.test(a))g=a+(b||
"");else{c=k.paths;e=k.pkgs;g=a.split("/");for(h=g.length;h>0;h-=1)if(i=g.slice(0,h).join("/"),f=e[i],i=c[i]){G(i)&&(i=i[0]);g.splice(0,h,i);break}else if(f){c=a===f.name?f.location+"/"+f.main:f.location;g.splice(0,h,c);break}g=g.join("/")+(b||".js");g=(g.charAt(0)==="/"||g.match(/^[\w\+\.\-]+:/)?"":k.baseUrl)+g}return k.urlArgs?g+((g.indexOf("?")===-1?"?":"&")+k.urlArgs):g},load:function(a,b){j.load(h,a,b)},execCb:function(a,b,c,e){return b.apply(e,c)},onScriptLoad:function(a){if(a.type==="load"||
la.test((a.currentTarget||a.srcElement).readyState))I=null,a=J(a),h.completeLoad(a.id)},onScriptError:function(a){var b=J(a);if(!i(b.id))return B(H("scripterror","Script error",a,[b.id]))}}}};j({});aa(j);if(w&&(t=A.head=document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0],C=document.getElementsByTagName("base")[0]))t=A.head=C.parentNode;j.onError=function(b){throw b;};j.load=function(b,c,e){var i=b&&b.config||{},g;if(w)return g=i.xhtml?document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml","html:script"):document.createElement("script"),
g.type=i.scriptType||"text/javascript",g.charset="utf-8",g.async=!0,g.setAttribute("data-requirecontext",b.contextName),g.setAttribute("data-requiremodule",c),g.attachEvent&&!(g.attachEvent.toString&&g.attachEvent.toString().indexOf("[native code")<0)&&!S?(L=!0,g.attachEvent("onreadystatechange",b.onScriptLoad)):(g.addEventListener("load",b.onScriptLoad,!1),g.addEventListener("error",b.onScriptError,!1)),g.src=e,E=g,C?t.insertBefore(g,C):t.appendChild(g),E=null,g;else ca&&(importScripts(e),b.completeLoad(c))};
w&&N(document.getElementsByTagName("script"),function(b){if(!t)t=b.parentNode;if(u=b.getAttribute("data-main")){if(!p.baseUrl)D=u.split("/"),da=D.pop(),ea=D.length?D.join("/")+"/":"./",p.baseUrl=ea,u=da;u=u.replace(ba,"");p.deps=p.deps?p.deps.concat(u):[u];return!0}});define=function(b,c,e){var i,g;typeof b!=="string"&&(e=c,c=b,b=null);G(c)||(e=c,c=[]);!c.length&&x(e)&&e.length&&(e.toString().replace(ha,"").replace(ia,function(b,e){c.push(e)}),c=(e.length===1?["require"]:["require","exports","module"]).concat(c));
if(L&&(i=E||ga()))b||(b=i.getAttribute("data-requiremodule")),g=z[i.getAttribute("data-requirecontext")];(g?g.defQueue:P).push([b,c,e])};define.amd={jQuery:!0};j.exec=function(b){return eval(b)};j(p)}})(this);
```

Comment: gzipping, or some other compression format.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The file you are looking at is minimised (a form of compression that produces valid code in fewer characters). But what PageSpeed is talking about is gzip compression which compresses the file into a much smaller version that is not valid code and has to be decompressed on the client before executing. Without knowing more about your server setup, I can't tell you how to enable this but it is normally pretty simple. Google [insert server tech here] gzip compression

Comment: Thanks Rob, we are using play framework. Can this be done using require.js?

Comment: I know nothing about the play framework (and very little about java in general) but it should not matter which framework you are using, it is the web server you are using that matters. I vaguely remember that Tomcat is one of the more common java web servers in which case http://viralpatel.net/blogs/enable-gzip-compression-in-tomcat/ may be of use.

Comment: Or check out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10778127/how-to-enable-gzip-compression-on-play-framework-1-app-on-heroku-cedar

Comment: require.js is the asset being served. It has no control over (and shouldn't care) whether or not it is gzipped.